# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, overwrite

1. Took Screenshot and saved to ( D://Myimages//logo.jpg )
2. again Took screenshot and saving in same folder ( overwrite ) ( D://Myimages//logo.jpg )

But unable to overwrite the images in same path, getting "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.".

i wanted to overwrite the images in same path.

Comment: Add the code. Show us how you save file and then re-save it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have opened the first image with some viewer and did not close that viewer when you tried to overwrite the existing image with a new one.